# ping check in perl command doesn't work

Tags: perl, ping, die

So let's say I ping an arbitrary host that is down or can't access for whatever reason.

If I were to do this in terminal

```
ping -c 2 DOWNED_HOST_NAME_HERE
```

I would get:

```
ping: unknown host DOWNED_HOST_NAME_HERE
```

However, this line of code isn't causing the script to die when I need it to.

```
my $ping_check = `ping -c 2 $host`;


if ($ping_check =~ /ping: unknown host $host/){

    die("Error: Cannot currently access host.");

}
```

I cannot use the Net::Ping for this script, I have to use basic perl.  Wouldn't this cause the script to error out?  I noticed when I warned $ping_check, it outputted an empty string.

Comment: Perhaps your question should be "How can I use Net::Ping with these limitations?". `Net::Ping` is a core module in Perl 5, and there is no real reason you cannot use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $ping_check = `ping -c 2 $host 2>&1`;
```

The error message is being printed to stderr.  The result of your command is stdout.
`2>&1` combines stderr `2` with stdout `1`

I always use [`Net::Ping`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html) for that though.  It's gives you a lot more control and is more portable.

Comment: Especially since `Net::Ping` is part of core.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. And I didn't realize that Net::Ping was port of Core. I thought it would have to be installed on another machine if the script was moved over there..

Comment: @user1768884 Try `corelist Net::Ping` at the command prompt. It is a handy command.